# Storing and using a trained neural network

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, recurrent-neural-network, heavy-computation

I am trying to develop a neural network to predict timeseries.

As far as I have understood, I am training my neural network with a training set and validate it with a test set.

When I am satisfied with my results, I can use my neural network to predict new values, and the neural network itself is basically just all the weights I have adjusted using my training sets.

Is this correct?

If so, I should only train my network once, and then just use my network (the weights) to predict future values. How do you normally avoid re-computing the entire network? Should I save all the weights in a database or something, so I can always access it without having to train it again?

If my understanding is correct, I can benefit from making the heavy computation on a dedicated computer (e.g. a supercomputer) and then just use my network on a webserver, an iPhone app or something like that, but I don't know how to store it.

Comment: Probably you can use `pickle` to store your trained neural net into a file. See https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html.

Comment: If you are using a neural network framework, please mention it, since that framework might have APIs to load/save the weights.

Answer (score 5):

To make your Neural Network *persistent*, you can [`pickle`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html) it. You would not need to recompute the weights of the *trained-pickled* network, and all you need do is unpickle the network and use it to make new predictions.

There are libraries like [`joblib`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_persistence.html) that can be used for more efficient *serialization/pickling*.

The question of whether to retrain a NN is not trivial. That depends on what exactly you're using the network for; say [Reinforcement learning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reinforcement_learning#Algorithms_for_control_learning) may require that you retrain with new beliefs. But in some cases, and probably in this, it may be sufficient to use a trained network once and always, or to retrain in a future where you have more field data.